# Blockly restrict input_value to another block

Tags: javascript, google-blockly

In my Blockly project, I have two 3 blocks `rcm_a`, `rcm_b` and `rcm_c`.

```
Blockly.defineBlocksWithJsonArray([{
  "type": "rcm_c",
  "message0": "Requirement block- rcm_a: %1 rcm_b: %2",
  "args0": [
    {
      "type": "input_value",
      "name": "rcm_a"
    },
    {
      "type": "input_value",
      "name": "rcm_b",
      "check": ["rcm_b"]
    }
  ],
  "output": "Text",
  "colour": "%{BKY_LOOPS_HUE}"
}]);
```

As you can see the above code of `rcm_c`, I am trying to restrict the second input to be of block `rcm_b`, and that apparently doesn't seem to be working. The same input will not accept any input type. Here's `rcm_b`'s code:

```
Blockly.defineBlocksWithJsonArray([{
  "type": "rcm_b",
  "message0": "rcm_b %1",
  "args0": [
    {
      "type": "input_value",
      "name": "VALUE1",
      "check": "String"
    }
  ],
  "output": "Text",
  "colour": "%{BKY_LOOPS_HUE}"
}]);
```

I tried following [this guide](https://developers.google.com/blockly/guides/create-custom-blocks/type-checks#statement_stacks)'s Statement Stacks section (I am aware that I am trying to type check inputs and not statements) to achieve type-checking. What am I doing wrong?

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, seems like the 'output' of `rcm_b` needed to be `rcm_b`!